# Form validation do CodeIgniter não permite acentos e outros caracteres "br"

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou usando a regra **"alpha_numeric_spaces"** para validar letras e números com espaço, mas quando uso algum caractere especial ou letras como "ç", a validação não passa, existe alguma forma de contornar isso ou só criando uma regra especial?

Ex:

```
 $validator->set_rules('nome', 'Nome', 'min_length[3]|max_length[60]|alpha_numeric_spaces');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É preciso criar sua própria regra. Veja só como é a implementação `alpha_numeric_spaces` do CodeIgniter:

```
public function alpha_numeric_spaces($str) {
    return (bool) preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9 ]+$/i', $str);
}
```

Ou seja, *insensitivamente* (`/i`) irá validar strings que contenham apenas 1 ou mais (`+$`) letras de A até Z, algarismos de 0 até 9  ou espaços. E você vai precisar de `\p{L}` na regex de validação do seu input, para deixar passar qualquer caractere acentuado do alfabeto latino, inclusive *ç*:

```
$validator->set_rules('nome', 'Nome', array('trim', 'regex_match[/[\p{L}0-9 ]+$/i]'));
```

Senão você pode apenas acrescentar o *ç* dentro da regra: `[A-Z0-9Ç ]`.

Comment: Obrigado, mas onde eu coloca essa função? tenho que criar uma classe e extender outra e redeclarar a função?

Comment: Olá! A função que foi demonstrada não precisa colocar em lugar nenhum, ela já está nos fontes do CodeIgniter, é só para apreciação. O que é necessário é reescrever a linha da validação do seu input, retirando seu `alpha_numeric_spaces` e inserindo `regex_match[/[\p{L}0-9 ]+$/i]`.